# Why we hear almost same sound from both end of a rod when we hit just one end of it?

Tags: waves, acoustics, elasticity

Suppose I hit a solid rod as at its cross section as perpendicular as possible. As longitudinal sound wave will travel towards other end of the rod. I should hear a loud sound at the other end of the rod. But why I hear virtually same sound on the particular end I hit? Shouldn't there be very little sound on that end as sound wave travels the direction opposite to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the sound waves reach the other side of the rod, they get partially reflected. The reflected waves have a lower amplitude than the original waves. The missing energy has been used to generate sound waves in air.

The waves will bounce back and forth in the rod, while slowly losing energy due to the generation of sound waves in the air on both sides of the rod.

This effect also explains why the sound you hear coming from the rod lasts much longer than the original hitting lasted.

Comment: Also, the speed of sound in a solid rod will usually be much higher than the speed in air. For most metals, the speed of sound is about 5000 m/s, compared with about 340 m/s in air. So the sound wave in the rod can travel along it and be reflected back to the end that you hit, *before* you hear  any sound from the other end of the rod traveling through the air.